# Use `any` with an `async_generator` Inside a Generator Expression

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-asyncio

If I have a regular iterable object in Python I can use `any` and a generator comprehension to get boolean. E.g.

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Pathlib("/foo/bar/baz")
has_contents = any(path.iterdir())
```

And I can do the same thing with an `async_generator` and list comprehension:

```py
is_empty = any([x async for x in async_generator])
```

But it doesn't seem to be possible to do the same with an `async_generator`and a generator comprehension.

```py
not_empty = any(x async for x in foo.iter())
```

raises

```py
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

Is there a way to use an `async_generator` inside a generator comprehension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not using an `async_generator` in a generator comprehension. That part is fine.

```
>>> async def ag():
...     yield 0
...     yield 1
... 
>>> (x async for x in ag())
<async_generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fffe34fd640>
```

The issue is *consuming* an async generator with a function that expects a synchronous iterator.

In this case, you can't iterate it with the regular `for x in ...` syntax, and you shouldn't pass it to functions that expect a synchronous iterator, such as `any`.  You'll see the same problem with `list(...)`.

Comment: That makes sense. So if I wanted to do the same thing I should write my own function to consume the async generator.

Comment: @Batman Yep, you got it.